# Find the right layer header for a corrupt pcap

Tags: digital-forensics, networking, wireshark

So the problem is that i have a corrupt pcap file. You can find a the pcap file [here][1]. 
First i did the file command on it : `the.pcap: tcpdump capture file (little-endian) - version 2.4, capture length 24)`

So i thought Wireshark could open it easily and then i might be able to find any key/flag by analyzing the packets.
But opening it with wireshark just gave me an error "network type 216 unknown or unsupported". So first, i did some research on the different layers types for a pcap.Here is the [link](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) to the different value of layer header. As expected the type with the value 216 has no reference so i need to change the 216 value to the right one? But how ? how can i know which one is appropriate ?

After googling a little bit i've seen that we can change the type's value manually.

```
00000000  D4 C3 B2 A1  02 00 04 00   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00   ................
00000010  18 00 00 00  D8 00 00 00   8E 6E 6E 52  A9 CB 00 00
```

Below you can see the first bytes of the pcap file and the byte D8 is the type's value which here is equal to 216. Should i try to edit a program which modify the original pcap file with all the existing type value and see which one works ? or is there any way to directly to know which value is the right one ?

If someone has some hint, it would be great. Thanks again and bye.

Comment: How did you create the pcap file? This could be anything from a file that isn't pcap to the 2nd part of a file that has been cut in the middle to an unkonwn compression to a file that got corrupted in transfer, so without much more information, and possibly a link to the file, we won't be able to help you much.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer i will reedit my question. With a link to the file and the different tests i have done. This is not a pcap file that i created, it s an exercise. So i would say it's not surprising that there is a problem with that pcap file. ( i ll give a link). Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But opening it with wireshark just gave me an error "network type 216 unknown or unsupported"

That's because nobody's contributed support for DLT_LINUX_EVDEV to Wireshark.

There does not appear to be anything at all corrupt about that file; if it were corrupt, Wireshark would have indicated that.  "network type XXX unknown or unsupported" doesn't mean the file is corrupt, it just means that Wireshark doesn't happen to handle that particular link-layer header type value.

Let's look at the header:

D4 C3 B2 A1: That's a little-endian pcap magic number.  So far, so good.

02 00: That's a little-endian major version number of 2.

04 00: That's a little-endian minor version number of 4.  2.4 is the current pcap file format version number; so far, so good.

00 00 00 00: That's the time zone offset, which is usually 0.

00 00 00 00: That's the time stamp accuracy, which is usually 0.

18 00 00 00: That's a little-endian snapshot length of 0x18 or 24.

D8 00 00 00: That's a little-endian link-layer header type of 0xD8, or 216, or DLT_LINUX_EVDEV.

What follows are records for packets:

8E 6E 6E 52: That's a little-endian seconds-since-January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC value of 0x526E6E8E, or 1382968974, or Mon Oct 28 07:02:54 2013 Pacific Standard Time - i.e., a bit more than a year and a half ago.

A9 CB 00 00: That's a little-endian microseconds-since-that-second value of 0xCBA9, or 52137.

18 00 00 00: That's a little-endian count of bytes captured, with a value of 0x18, or 24.

18 00 00 00: That's a little-endian count of bytes that were actually in the message (the capture process can truncate data past a certain point; that's what the snapshot length in the file indicates), with a value of 0x18, or 24.

And the 24 bytes of packet data are:
8E 6E 6E 52
00 00 00 00
A9 CB 00 00
00 00 00 00
04 00 04 00
1C 00 00 00

"EVDEV" refers to the [evdev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev) driver in Linux, which allows various providers of user input (keyboards, mice, tablets, trackpads, joysticks, etc.) to plug into it, and it merges the streams of input events into a single stream that can be read by programs such as the X server or the Weston server for Wayland.

Its events are described in the Linux "input.h" header as

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    __u16 type;
    __u16 code;
    __s32 value;
};
```

so that's a 64-bit(?) seconds-since-January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, a 64-bit microseconds since that second, a 16-bit type, a 16-bit code, and a 32-bit value.

All, unfortunately, in host byte order, according to the discussion on the tcpdump-workers mailing list.  This host is, apparently, little-endian.

And the time stamp duplicates the one in the pcap record header.

So we have:

8E 6E 6E 52 00 00 00 00 - 0x526E6E8E, or the same time stamp as in the packet record header;

A9 CB 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 0xCBA9, or the same microseconds-since-that-second as in the packet record header;

04 00 - 0x0004, or a type of 4, or "EV_MSC" according to the Linux header, and which is "Used to describe miscellaneous input data that do not fit into other types" according to [the Linux event codes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt);

04 00 - 0x0004, or a code of 4, or "MSC_SCAN" for EV_MSC messages according to the Linux header;

1C 00 00 00 - 0x1C, or a value of 30.

And then we have the next packet:

8E 6E 6E 52 - same second

A9 CB 00 00 - same microsecond

18 00 00 00 - same length, not surprising as all evdev messages are 24 bytes long

18 00 00 00 - again, same length

8E 6E 6E 52 00 00 00 00 - same (duplicate) second

A9 CB 00 00 00 00 00 00 - same (duplicate) microsecond

01 00 - 0x0001, or type "EV_KEY", "Used to describe state changes of keyboards, buttons, or other key-like devices"

1C 00 - 0x001C, or 28, which is "KEY_ENTER", the meaning of which should be obvious (although the one on the laptop on which I'm typing this says "return" in larger letters below and only says "enter" in smaller letters above :-))

00 00 00 00 - value of 0

and so on.

So I'm absolutely 100% certain that it *is* a pcap file, and isn't even a corrupted one; it just happens to contain messages that Wireshark doesn't understand.

The link type, in the sense of "link-layer header type", appears only once, in the file's header, so there's no reason to expect anything else to be a link type in the file - pcap *simply doesn't support* different link types in one single capture file, unless a hack like DLT_PPI is used.  So that part of the argument against it being a pcap file is invalid.

As for addresses, there's no guarantee that a given DLT_ type *has* any addresses, and evdev events don't, so that doesn't apply, either.

In any case, if you want to open it in Wireshark, you'll need to find or write a dissector for it.

Comment: Seems my automatic assumption - tcp capture file == network trace - was wrong. Thank you for teaching me something new.

Comment: Great analysis!!

Comment: Wow this analysis was great i really need to read more documentation about evdev and the different link layer header type. Thank you very much !

Comment: I finally success the exercise thank you again!  But may i ask how you knew it was DLT_LINUX_EVDEV ? i mean i couldn't link the 216 type value with that type of link header.

Comment: I looked in the libpcap source's pcap/bpf.h file and, being a libpcap core developer, I looked in my mail archives for the discussion of it.  Then I looked at the Linux source.  (The person who proposed it didn't offer a detailed precise description or a link to such a description, so we didn't put it in the [list of link-layer types](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html); people shouldn't ask for link-layer types if they don't have a precise description, but sometimes they do, unfortunately.

Comment: I see, i'm glad that you guys helped me.  Thank you , have a good day !

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure this isn't a pcap file at all, despite what file says, and the D8 doesn't seem to be a network type at all.

First, because D8 (216) isn't a valid link type according to http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html.

Second, because hexdumping a bit more of the file yields this:

```
00000000  d4 c3 b2 a1 02 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00000010  18 00 00 00 d8 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52 a9 cb 00 00   .........nnR....
00000020  18 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52 00 00 00 00   .........nnR....
00000030  a9 cb 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 04 00 1c 00 00 00   ................
00000040  8e 6e 6e 52 a9 cb 00 00 18 00 00 00 18 00 00 00   .nnR............
00000050  8e 6e 6e 52 00 00 00 00 a9 cb 00 00 00 00 00 00   .nnR............
00000060  01 00 1c 00 00 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52 a9 cb 00 00   .........nnR....
00000070  18 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52 00 00 00 00   .........nnR....
00000080  a9 cb 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
```

If you restructure this a bit, focussing on the 8e 6e 6e 52 (.nnR) sequence:

```
0000 d4 c3 b2 a1 02 00 04 00
0008 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0010 18 00 00 00 d8 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52             a9 cb 00 00
0020 18 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52 00 00 00 00 a9 cb 00 00 
0034 00 00 00 00 
0038 04 00 04 00 1c 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52             a9 cb 00 00
0048 18 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52 00 00 00 00 a9 cb 00 00
005c 00 00 00 00
0060 01 00 1c 00 00 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52             a9 cb 00 00
0070 18 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 8e 6e 6e 52 00 00 00 00 a9 cb 00 00
```

you see that a) there is clearly a pattern to the file, and b), if the first `d8` is a link type, then `1c`  and `00`  should be link types as well. But it doesn't make any sense for link types that vary so much, and have the same content, to be included in one single capture file.

Also, there's nothing that resembles anything like a source and destination ip address, or at least mac address if the protocol wasn't tcp/ip.

Maybe someone just saved the payload of a tcp connection, and somehow made a mistake when saving it, giving it a tcpdump header. But i'm 99% sure this isnt a corrupted tcpdump file; this seems to be something very different.

Now if you told me that this file was created 25 years ago on ARCNET hardware running an IPX protocol, i might reconsider, since arcnet didn't have mac addresses, just network card numbers between 1-255 which had to be configured using dip switches, and IPX reused the network card number for addressing. But unless you have a good explanation how the file was created, and which kind of packets and payload it should contain, which could explain the structure, i'd say this isn't tcpdump or pcap at all, and patching a byte or two won't help you open it in wireshark.

Comment: Oh i see, i'm sorry but as i don't know many things about network i was fooled by the file command. Anyway your answer helps me, i'll now try  to see that file differently. Thanks again and have a good day.